# How to use sed to delete all the chars from the last dot on?

Tags: sed

How can I use `sed` to delete all the chars from the last dot on?

e.g.:

```
ns:base.cocktails.cocktail_garnish
ns:user.maport.cocktail.cocktail_recipe
ns:base.cocktails.cocktail_drinkware
ns:user.pjf.default_domain.chicken_breed
ns:user.radiusrs.default_domain.astrological_sign
ns:base.disaster2.type_of_tornado
```

I want to get:

```
ns:base.cocktails
ns:user.maport
ns:base.cocktails
ns:user.pjf.default_domain
ns:user.radiusrs.default_domain
ns:base.disaster2
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix usage, belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: maybe... `sed` is a programming language.

Answer (score 2):

That's basic.

```
sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="."} NF--' file
```

But `sed` is better for this job.

---

Using the `sed` regex:

```
awk '{sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"")}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/' file
```

Used greed to find the last `.` and delete thereafter.